# nokia here maps geocoding and display map

Tags: geocoding, here-api

please, could someone explain me how can I manage, in Here Maps code, `nokia.maps.map.Display listener` and `nokia.places.search.manager.geocode` method?
I have markers to be geocoded, in geocode "oncomplete" it waits for the request to be completed, after that it listens when map display is ready, so as it happens asynchronously, it sometimes displays on browser a map not finished yet, this is because `map.zoomTo(bbox, false)` was not executed.

How can I manage these two events?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goPageOnLoad() {
   container = new nokia.maps.map.Container();
   map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(document.getElementById('gmapcanvas'),
   { components:[ infoBubbles, new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(), new
   nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar(), new
   nokia.maps.map.component.Overview(), new
   nokia.maps.map.component.TypeSelector(), new
   nokia.maps.map.component.ScaleBar() ] });
   addMarkersGeoLoc(map,container); 
}

function addMarkersGeoLoc(map,container) {
     countMarkerGeoLoc=1; coordinate = new
     nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(0, 0); startGeoCode('Via Roma 2, 16038 Santa
     Margherita Ligure GE '); 
} 



function startGeoCode(addressStringt) {
    nokia.places.search.manager.geoCode({ 
       searchTerm : addressString,
       onComplete: function(data, requestStatus){ 
          if(data != null){ 
             coordinate = 
             new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(data.location.position.latitude,
             data.location.position.longitude);
             var marker = new
             nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(coordinate, {brush: {color: "#FF0000"}});
             marker.addListener( CLICK, function (evt) {
             infoBubbles.openBubble(content, marker.coordinate); } );
             container.objects.add(marker); 
             managersFinished++; 
          } 
          else {
               managersFinished++; alert('Address: '+addressString+', is not
               localizable.'); 
          } 
          if(managersFinished === countMarkerGeoLoc) {
             map.objects.add(container); 
             map.set('zoomLevel', 14);
             map.addListener("displayready", function () { 
                  map.set('center',
                  [40.645304, 14.874063]); 
                  bbox = container.getBoundingBox(); 
                  if(bbox !=null){ 
                    map.zoomTo(bbox, false); 
                  } 
             }); 
           } 
         } 
      }); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method would be to wait for the `displayready` event before starting your geocoding.

```
function goPageOnLoad() {
   container = new nokia.maps.map.Container();
   map = new nokia.maps.map.Display
.. etc...
   map.addListener('displayready', function () {
     addMarkersGeoLoc(map,container); 
   }, false);
```

The other alternative would be to have a global `bbox` variable and use `zoomTo()` twice - either on `displayready` or on `managersFinished === countMarkerGeoLoc` i.e.

```
var bbox;

...

function goPageOnLoad() {
   container = new nokia.maps.map.Container();
   map = new nokia.maps.map.Display
.. etc...
   map.addListener("displayready", function () {
    if(bbox){map.zoomTo(bbox, false);}
});


...


 if(managersFinished === countMarkerGeoLoc) {
   map.objects.add(container); 
   bbox = container.getBoundingBox(); 
   map.zoomTo(bbox, false);
```

Either the first or the second of the `zoomTo()` functions must fire to move the map.